# Default exit function implementation

Tags: c++, c, linux, exit, system-calls

I need to implement default behavior of exit call. I don't know what should I do and what is the most suitable  way to do this. I have read that it should close file descriptors and something else. 
Should I close default streams (stdout,err and in) ? 
How to exit from nested functions calls ? Using goto  is bad practice, what is the best way to break out ?
Thanks.

Comment: "How to exit from nested functions calls" - what do you mean by that? And yes, you should close all file descriptors.

Comment: "default behavior of exit call" - Are you referring to [atexit()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit)? Are you talking about C++ or C? I think you might need to provide more context.

Comment: How can I close all desciptors ? Including std streams ? Iterate through descriptors in /proc/id/fds ?

Comment: `Using goto is bad practice` is a religious statement. You should evaluate if in your case a simple goto wouldnt be simpler than several conditional returns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do all of the things listed in [`exit(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exit), then invoke the [`_exit(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/exit) system call.  Alternatively, use [`longjmp(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/longjmp) to jump back up to the `main()` function, then return from it.  This invokes the same behavior as calling `exit(3)`, and is just as dependent on the C runtime, so if `exit(3)` is unavailable for some reason, returning from `main()` will probably not work correctly either.

Unfortunately, AFAIK there is no portable way to enumerate all of the functions which may have been registered with `atexit(3)` and `on_exit(3)`, so you'll have to keep track of those manually (i.e. every time you call `atexit(3)` or `on_exit(3)`, append the function pointer to a list).  Flushing [`stdio(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/stdio) is 3 straightforward [`fflush(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) calls.

You do not need to close any streams or file descriptors; the OS should do that automatically (the OS must not leak streams and fd's, so it is responsible for cleaning them up).

NB: `longjmp()` is almost always wrong under C++; throw an exception instead.  It generally should only be used under straight C.